# Typhoeus Issue while raising request from testing server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, typhoeus

I am using Typhoeus gem to send http requests to an API. It's working from my system. But while sending the same from TESTING server it's not giving the desired response. I want to know what could be the problem? Please help me.

MY code:

```
data = {"auth_token"=>"abcd" ,"employee" => {"method" => "add_employee"}}
header =  { "Content-Type" => "application/json","Accept"=>"application/json"}
request = Typhoeus::Request.post("www.example.com",:body=> data.to_json,:headers => header)
```

Comment: what response is it giving, what is the desired response?

Comment: desired response is, "employee created successfully" but instead of that its returning empty response.

Comment: Have you tried hitting the endpoint with curl from the faulty server to figure out if it's a problem with the server or Typhoeus? maybe there's some sort of firewall blocking your request there.

Comment: @MikeH-R curl command is working in the faulty server

Comment: And there's no error, just an empty body? what exactly is being returned?

Comment: faulty server is returning :response_body=>"[]"

Comment: @MikeH-R curl command is working means the problem with server or typhoeus?

Comment: not sure, just seems to rule out firewall. hmmm... sorry I'm not sure if I have any more advice. Oh, it's not because you're trying to create a new object that's already there is it? (since it's a post request, which is often used to create new objects on the server) if that is the case there really should be some sort of error message in the body though... good luck.